# Multiple User Models in cartalyst/sentinel with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cartalyst-sentinel

I'm using cartalyst/sentinel with laravel and I'm looking to use Multiple User Models with sentinel. its a yii application that I'm rewriting in laravel it has separate tables for each type of user like a client, admin, etc. with role base I have to create a relation with sentinel user model  but lot of queries are based on existing table keys. How can use different tables for authentication with laravel?

Answer (score 0):

If it's Sentinel then it has a config where you can set the role_user pivot table and set their roles (client, admin) using slug. Hope this helps